# Do I have to include classes from the same package in AOSP java?

Tags: java, android-source

I have a weird behavior in one service I am developing for AOSP.

It seems like I have to include classes even if they are in the same package, while this is normally not needed in java.
If I don't, I get `cannot find symbol` at compile time.

Is there some special rule applying to AOSP? Maybe some special settings I need to fix in Android.mk?

Comment: It should be no different than Java. Maybe your class is private, not public ? Show some sample code.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong, but now it works. Maybe I should just delete the question. I can't even post the not-working code because I don't have it

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a typo in one of your class's package statements ;)